# How do I remove THIN layer of carpet glue from concrete?

Tags: concrete, carpet, glue, removal

The folks who owned this house before us were the cheapest people around. They glued carpet to our concrete floor with a *very thin* layer of glue. Now, I'm having a terrible time scraping it off. I tried using some adhesive remover we got from Lowe's, but it doesn't really seem to be having any effect other than making it wet :(

My local hardware stores include: **Locke & Lowe's.** There's also a local store that rents tools, but I'm not sure the extent of their selection, I was able to rent an auger there once for digging fence poles, just as an example.

Any suggestions on solvents? Tools?

Comment: Any idea what kind of adhesive? Test small spots with different solvents. Acetone, mineral spirits, denatured alcohol, etc.  Be cautious as many have hazardous vapors or even flammable/ explosive in confined areas.

Comment: Some of these glues can be softened with a wallpaper steamer and scraped off with a lot less mess than a concrete grinder and quicker than you think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tool rental places probably rent concrete grinders for big jobs like refinishing concrete floors and then you can use a sander that get get into corners.

[image: Floor Grinder]

Floor Grinder

[image: Concrete Sander]

Concrete Sander

You can probably rent one or both of these, depending on the amount of glue.  If it's just spotty you can probably use the hand sander.

Like I said, these are for professionally prepare floors for concrete finishing.  If it is thin you might try belt sander or palm sander, and buy a sampling of sand papers and see which works best.

[image: Belt Sander]

Belt Sander

[image: Palm Sander]

Palm Sander

Comment: lqlarry, thanks for your answer. My wife & I have been talking more about the sanders & the large cement grinder tonight. I'm going by the tool rental place tomorrow to see what they have available.

Comment: If you chose to grind the floor, be sure to get lots of abrasive pads. Adhesives will foul them quickly.

Answer (score 6):

We ended up using Krud Kutter Adhesive Remover, *several* pots of boiling water combined with a sturdy long handled floor scraper *(& elbo grease)* followed by a large orbital sander with 60 grit sanding screens.

This still didn't get all of the adhesive off :( but we have enough off and it's smooth enough for us to paint the floor, based on what I've been told & read online.

Hopefully, this will be helpful for someone else later on :)

Answer (score 5):

If the glue is still a bit tacky then first get a bag of flour and throw handfuls of it on the floor, sweep it around on the whole floor. That will make it much less messy to get up. Then get a 4-inch floor scraper with plenty of blades and go to town. Here is a picture of the scraper from Lowes. Although I would try to find one with a little longer handle.

[image: 4-inch scraper]

It takes awhile, but its really the easiest and cheapest method. You will spend a small fortune on sanding pads and tool rentals. You might be tempted to get the 8-inch floor scraper with the long handle. Don't, they are more work than they are worth for this particular job. Stick with the 4-inch scraper with around an 18-inch handle length, and don't try to scrape the full 4-inch width do about 2-inch sections at a time. Should come up with relative ease. The problem with sanding pads and grinders is that the glue gums them up too quickly and they become useless.

Comment: The flour method mentioned above worked quickly and cheaply for a small strip of carpet glue we had ringing the entire basement from previous owners carpet.